# 'str' object is not callable,object of type 'int' has no len(),TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
x = 1231
for i in x[::-1]:
    if i > i-1:
        print(i)
        break
```

Above code generates: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
x = 1231
for i in x(len(x)-1,0,-1):
    if i > i-1:
        print(i)
        break
```

above code generates: object of type 'int' has no len()

```
x = 1231
y = str(x)
for i in y(len(y)-1,0,-1):
    if i > i-1:
        print(i)
        break
```

and this above code generates: 'str' object is not callable

so i know the error here but i don't know how to solve this? what I am trying to achieve here is compare string elements in reverse way, which are int as input and print number if i > i-1 in range(i-1,0,i-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `range(len(y)-1,0,-1)` and check `y[i]`

```
x = 1231
y = str(x)
for i in range(len(y)-1,0,-1):
    if y[i] > y[i-1]:
        print(y[i])
        break
```